# Application of Baire category theorem on functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to solve the following task by using the Baire category theorem:

Let be $f: [0,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continous function such that

$$\forall t \geq 0: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(nt) = 0 $$

I have to show that $f$ satifies 
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} f(t)=0 $$

In our lecture we had the following version of the Baire category theorem:

Let be $(M,d)$ a complete metric space and $O_n \subset M$ open and dense.
Then $\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N} }O_n $ is dense in M.

I don't know how to use here the Baire category theorem especially how to create such open and dense subsets. Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance